# Setting column color in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin7

I have a Vaadin 7 Grid and I would like to set a color to a specific column.

```
Grid grid = new Grid(container);
grid.setColumnOrder("column1","column 2","column 3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the many column renderers. Easiest is probably the HTMLRenderer.

Example:

```
grid.addColumn("column1", String.class).setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer());
grid.addRow("data for column1", "data for column2", ...,
            "<h1 style="background-color:Red;">data for column3</h1>");
```

See also: https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-grid/#components.grid.generatedcolumns

Comment: This will set colour for the row right . I want to set colour for column header .

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code actually worked for me.I have been using Java 8  ,

```
Grid.setCellStyleGenerator((Grid.CellStyleGenerator) cellReference ->{
 cellReference.getGrid().getHeaderRow(rowIndex: 0).getCell("column name").setStyleName("bg-blue");
}
```

Note :- bg-blue is the css rule mentioned in CSS file .